# How to get the file name of the failed switch branch in libgit2?

Tags: c, libgit2

I can call the switch branch interface normally, but when the switch branch fails, I cannot get the specific file of the current branch failure. Viewing error info only shows "one or more conflict prevents checkout", if I want to get the detailed error file name, How to get detailed error information from the callback function or return value? (also include:Merge、Reset...)

```
// code

git_checkout_options opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE;

git_branch_lookup(&lookup, repo, branchname, GIT_BRANCH_LOCAL);

git_revparse_single(&treeish, repo, branchbane);

if(git_checkout_tree(repo, treeish, &opts)<0)

{
   /*
     just return "1 conflict prevents checkout",
     But I want to know which files is wrong
   */
   const git_error* error = giterr_last(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set a [`notify_cb`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/checkout.h#L279) in your [`git_checkout_options`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_checkout_options), and set your [`notify_flags`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/checkout.h#L273)  to include [`GIT_CHECKOUT_NOTIFY_CONFLICT`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/checkout.h#L219) .

Your notify callback that you provide will be invoked with the files that are changed in your working directory and preventing the checkout from occurring.

Comment: @Thomson, Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not so familiar with `libgit2` but it looks like you'll have to solve the conflict manually. The error that you get :

> 1 conflict prevents checkout

Tells you that there is a file with a conflict, but you'll have to iterate through your tree to find which one and to solve it.

The [status example from libgit2.org](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/ex/HEAD/status.html) would certainly be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just want to return a detailed error message in libgit2 instead of solving the error

Comment: @potter so iterate over the files to know which one have conflicts and add them to your returned error message but the API doesn't provide more info than what you already got.

Comment: “1 conflict" does not mean that the file status is conflict. It is just a description of the error message returned, and I want the function to throw an error file name.

Comment: @potter, yes I got that, but the API doesn't provide the file name so you have to investigate yourself which file is preventing to checkout and I think analyzing the status of the files is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I will analyze according to your method

Comment: You can't easily tell from calling status: if a file is changed in the working directory, it would prevent checkout from modifying it, but it's legal to do a checkout with a file changed in the working tree that checkout _wouldn't touch_.  You can't easily tell whether checkout _would_ modify a file without also diffing the checkout target.  This is further complicated because checkout can proceed when a file in the WD is modified to match the contents of the checkout target.